# dvi->PDF crashes (WinEdt v5.3, Windows 10)

Tags: dvipdf

I just installed the current version of MiKTeX and also did the "check for updates" from the MiKTeX console, which updated several packages.

I can compile my TeX file, and view it in Yap, but when I try to use dvi->PDF, I get a crash "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF67EB044E0 in dvipdfm.exe". I am using WinEdt v5.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: Executing miktex-dvipdfmx.exe from the command line generates the .pdf file, so the error is most likely in the command that WinEdt generates when I click the dvi->pdf button.

Comment: winedt 5.3 is *very* old, the current winedt has version number 10.3. If there is problem you won't get much support for it.